# json loader not working with Jest and react-native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm using a basic `react-native` + `jest`. But when I try to `import 'something.json'`, jest doesn't recognize it as json and gives me a syntax error.

I think the issue is just that react native has his own webpack config that's hidden to jest and I wonder if there's an already solved way to make jest follow the react-native webpack config.

Thanks a lot !